# Second Order Differential Equation Sturm Liouville Problem, eigenvalue properties

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

I have the spectral problem $X'' + (\alpha(x) - \lambda)X = 0$, with boundary conditions $X(0) = 0 = X(1)$. This is a Sturm Liouville problem, and the book I am reading says that clearly

$$
||\alpha(x)||_{L^{\infty}(0,1)} \geq \lambda_1 > \lambda_2 \ldots
$$

which I think makes sense, since we want non-trivial solutions, right?

But what about the ODE

$$
X'' + \alpha(x)X' - \lambda X = 0
$$

with the same boundary conditions? How would we go about knowing the relation between $\alpha(x)$ and the eigenvalues?

Comment: Hint: eliminate the term in $X'$ with the substitution $X(x)=u(x)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x\alpha(x')\,dx'\right)$.